# What is the time complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

In my class my teacher calculated the time complexity for this algorithm, relative to the number of sum operations executed:

[image]

She represented the cost of the algorithm  by the following sum:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^i\sum\limits_{k=1}^j 3 = \frac{n^3}{2} + \frac{3n^2}{2} + n $

The step by step used to solve the sum bellow:
[image]

```
n = 10
count=0
for i in range (0, n):
    for j in range (0, i):
        for k in range (0, j):
            count+=3

print count
```

Then, I wrote a algorithm in python to verify the solution, but it not produce the expected output, for example, for n = 10 we expected 660 operations, but it print 360.

Change the index to start with 1 like in the bellow didn't worked either, in fact it got more distance from the expected (252).

```
n = 10
count=0
for i in range (1, n):
    for j in range (1, i):
        for k in range (1, j):
            count+=3

print count
```

Comment: You cannot expect 860 operations, as 860 is not divisible by 3. Running loops as intended gives $count = 858$.

Comment: @EvilJS Sorry,  the 860 is a typo it should be 660. Where did you find the 858 ?

Comment: Very easy, I just executed your triple loop and got result - it was before the edit. From 0 to n inclusively. And without the last element it was 360. Now when you changed the code, if you do $count += 3$ it is not the same as sum of $i, j, k$ indices on every iteration. Please look at D.W. answer and comment, if you got result somehow, but describe it differently in pseudocode, differently in python and MathJax it is the most probable place of error.

Comment: @EvilJS My mistake, the only operation we should count is the sum in the most deep loop. Even so you are able produce 858 as output, or did you count the for operations ? Perdon my ignorance, but  can you elabore a little more how you got the 858 ?

Comment: I'm going to repeat my comment.  How *exactly* did you get 360?  You said you wrote an algorithm in Python, but you don't show us the Python; one possible error is that you wrote the Python wrong.  How have you ruled that out?  Note that your pseudocode at the top of the question does not match the Python at the bottom.

Comment: I would like to help you, I really do, but please take some time to proofread your question, use LaTeX and look at your codes, they all differ, this python, which is not python gives you some result. And now there is another code, but not included $x = 10$, none of your codes had variable $x$. Now one could wonder, is there also possibility that you run different code than show, or have two codes and run the bad one? There might be even pseudorandom generator with the same seed giving the result. I just want to show you that various things might happen, but we can only address visible ones.

Comment: The x = 10 should be n = 10. The complexity is based on the algorithm in the picture, and I try to write the algorithm in Python (in the answer) to verify the complexity. It's is possible that my Python algorithm is wrong(but I was unable to identify the problem), excuting it for n=10 gives 360 operations. The Python code is in my Answer.

Comment: @D.W. I got the 360 running the python algorithm posted in my answer, You said that the algorithm is not equivalent with the Pseudocode, is because the index start in 0? I tried with index starting with 1 and I got 252.

Comment: Now, you need to make index _reach_ n, rather than go just up to it, so instead of range(1,n), it should be range(1,m) for some m such that ​ n < m . ​ ​ ​ To avoid n+1, one also needs ​ m ≤ n+1 . ​ ​ ​ Combining those gives ​ n < m ≤ n+1 . ​ ​ ​ The simplest such m is obviously ​ m = n+1 , ​ so your initial range should be `range(1,n+1)`. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Thanks! Now it works as expected. Sorry for the noob questions. Can you post your comment as answer so I mark it as accepted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, you need to make index reach n, rather than go just up to it,

so instead of range(1,n), it should be range(1,m) for some m such that ​ n < m .

To avoid n+1, one also needs ​ m ≤ n+1 . ​ ​ ​ Combining those gives ​ n < m ≤ n+1 .

The simplest such m is obviously ​ m = n+1 , ​ so your initial range should be `range(1,n+1)`.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, `range(0,n)` iterates through the values `0`, `1`, `2`, .., `n-1` (but not `n`).  Therefore, your summation should have been

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \cdots$$

rather than

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \cdots$$

and similarly for the other sums as well.

Comment: 0 to n-1 and 1 to n are not equivalent? Anyway change the ranges to 1 to n-1 did not work either.

Comment: Just to clarify the original program is not written is python is a PseudoCode with `i  <-  1 to n do`. What's bother me is even if a change the program range (1 to n) it will no produce the expected output.

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro, rather than posting comments, I suspect you need to edit your question. I can only go by what's in the question; I can't read your mind.  Your question says "Looking at this algorithm write in python"....  If you say it's in Python, we'll take you at your word.  If it's not written in Python, you need to edit the post to define your notation (e.g., what *you* mean by `range`), *and* tell us exactly how you measured how many operations were performed (not the calculations; but how did you run the algorithm and get 360?).

Comment: Ok, thanks for you suggestion I update the question with the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher was incorrect in thinking that a triple summation of i + j + k (in Python, temp += i + j + k) equals a triple of summation of 1 + 1 + 1 (in Python, temp += 1 + 1 + 1 or temp += 3).  See my step-by-step work attached at bottom.

The triple summation of 1 + 1 + 1, i.e. incrementing by 3, over k from 1 to j, j from 1 to i, and i from 1 to n, equals (n**3 + 3*n**2 + 2*n) / 2.  For n = 10, for instance, 1320/2 = 660.  Simple Python 3 code confirms this math.

In Python 3,
n = 10
count=0
for i in range (1, n+1):
    for j in range (1, i+1):
        for k in range (1, j+1):
            count+=3
print(count)
660

The more intricate summation of (i + j + k) over k from 1 to j, j from 1 to i, and i from 1 to n, equals (n**4 + 4*n**3 + 5*n**2 + 2*n) / 4, which is exactly (n+1)/2 times the previous sum.  Can you deduce why?  Because, on average, the quantities i, j, and k will be halfway between 1 and n.
For n = 10, for instance, 14520/4 = 3630.  Again, Python 3 code that increments count += i + j + k confirms this result at n = 10.

n = 10
count=0
for i in range (1, n+1):
    for j in range (1, i+1):
        for k in range (1, j+1):
            count+= i + j + k
print(count)
3630

[image: Triple summation of i + j + k]

Comment: Please refrain from posting mathematical formulae as images (and especially in wrong orientation). This site provides full LaTeX support.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation does not match the algorithm written in the pseudo-code.
In the pseudo-code:

`for i ← 1 to n do`

means i could take n values from 1 to n.
for simple, let's consider the last iteration, namely i=n. Then consider the second loop:

`for j ← 1 to j do`

could be reduced to:

`for j ← 1 to n do`

That's to say, j could also take n values from 1 to n. But for your implementation in python,

`for i in range (0, n)`

i could take n values from 0 to n-1. Let's also consider the last iteration, namely i=n-1. Unfortunately, for the second loop:

`for j in range (0, n-1)`

here j can only take n-1 values from 0 to n-2. Obviously mismatched to the original algorithm. Two ways to solve your problem:

Index start from 1 and use LCRC rule:

`for i in range (1, n+1):
    for j in range (1, i+1):
        for k in range (1, j+1):
            count+=3`

or start from index 0, but use LCRC rule for all inner loops:

`for i in range (0, n):
    for j in range (0, i+1):
        for k in range (0, j+1):
            count+=3`

The first one is preferred as it exactly match the algorithm. But the second one could let you clearly understand the difference between the outer loop and inner loops.